# Build fails with "Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build-error

I just insert the `NVActivityIndicatorView` library and then I remove this framework in to trash. When I build the project it's showing following image.

> Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: I have the same problem, and I'm sure that is some path error trying to find the bridging

Answer (score 41):

Check your TargetName-Bridging-Header.h location in project. Open

> **Target** -> **Built Settings** -> **Objective-C Bridging Header**

[image: See screen here]

Answer (score 33):

In my case.

1. Go to Build Settings and search for `Objective-C Bridging Header` and double click to its value.
2. clear the path given in it. (if any)
3. Now drag your Bridging Header file and drop it to `Objective-C Bridging Header` value view.
4. Finally clean your project and build. (Its Done).

**Note:** Collective, just change the path of Bridging Header File in your Build Settings.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I renamed the file from disk and edited the line to reflect the new name.

Comment: In my case I entered the name of bridging header file but path should be entered there as drag and drop worked. Perfect

Answer (score 1):

check your TargetName-Bridging-Header.h location in project. This file should be in root folder

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to be at the root if you follow Taras's answer below about specifying its location in your build settings 

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with React Native, delete you bridging header file and then create a swift file under your Target. XCode will automatically ask you if you want to create bridging file.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on a React Native project. Make sure all values of the `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: XX.X` inside project.pbxproj is same as in Podfile `platform :ios, 'XX.X'`

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes can be from a revoked certificate which you have to update :|